# Is T4 template run every time it is requested?

Tags: c#, .net, templates, code-generation, t4

I am trying to setup an environment which would let me use a template to send out email to thousands of people. In all of this, performance is a key and I am trying to find out,
when `myscript.tt` is run, is it compiled and executed every time or is there a compiled object that can be reused for subsequent calls to execute the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you call this in a pre-compiled template:

```
string result = new MyTemplate().TransformText();
```

The template and its code (logic, etc) is created once but you then call the TransformText to generate the dynamically desired output. In your case I think you feed your template with different e-mail addresses each time you call TransformText.

This post will answer your question:

[Run-Time Text Generation with T4 Text Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/run-time-text-generation-with-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019)

More details here:

[Writing Code that Writes Code](https://www.developer.com/net/writing-code-that-writes-code.html#:~:text=T4%20in%20Action&text=Template%20code%20is%20executed%20when,whenever%20the%20app%20is%20compiled.))

Comment: "During the first step, the engine preprocesses the template: it parses the processing instructions, text and code blocks, generates a concrete TextTransformation class, and compiles it into a .NET assembly. During the second step, T4 engine creates an instance of the GeneratedTextTransformation class, calls its TransformText method and saves the string it returns to the output file." It is the second step that causes the confusion. I was convinced that pre-processed templates would only be created once and reused over time, but the second step is causing me some confusion. Thoughts ?

Comment: Above is an excerpt from Oleg's link you posted.

Comment: @brainydexter: you call this in a pre-compiled template: string `result = new MyTemplate().TransformText();` The template and its code (logic, etc) is created once but you then call the TransformText to generate the dynamically desired output. In your case I think you feed your template with different e-mail addresses each time you call TransformText.

Comment: Read Passing parameters in the constructor here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx